# Restore the original color after clicking on image button android

Tags: android, onclick, imagebutton

I have mentioned the following in the **onClick()** method:
`Ibutton1.setColorFilter(Color.argb(150, 155, 155, 155));`// this gives the button a gray tint when the button is clicked. where Ibutton1 is the instance of Imagebutton

Now I want that the tint should be removed after the button has been clicked and the activity has been started... 
Plz help

Comment: Got the answer at last.. using both OnClickListener and OnTouchListener simultaneously.. Thanx everyone for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use a selector for this.Check the same in the link below:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html

Thanks!

Comment: I dont want to use multiple images... Thats why i am using colorfilter for click events

Answer (score 0):

try using `lbutton1.clearColorFilter()` function on the desired event.

Comment: When should i call this function? If i am calling it after starting the activity its not working...

Comment: try calling it just before the startActivity() function call.Did that work?

Comment: Nope... not working... can you tell me any other solution to my prob?

Comment: can u describe what behavior you exactly want...is the activity taking some time to load waiting for something after the button is clicked ?

Comment: I want that when u click the image button a tint or box will form around it showing that the button is pressed... I dont want to use multiple image...